# Trouble Creating a React App: Module Not Found Error

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, modulenotfounderror

Whenever I write command for creating react app an error occur module not found.

The commands I write in terminal shell are:

```
node -v
npm -v
npx create-react-app my-app
```

after this creating command there is an error module not found and my file doesn't create.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install react-scripts@latest`, it should update/download the react tools you need